# Go to next Waterfall step from current step in bot framework v4

Tags: c#, authentication, botframework

I have a waterfall dialog that prompts user to pick a choice, either 'Yes' or 'No'. Upon user selection 'Yes', the bot do not continue to next waterfall dialog.

First Waterfall step.

```
private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> LoginStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext step, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var tokenResponse = (TokenResponse)step.Result;
        if (tokenResponse != null)
        {
            await step.Context.SendActivityAsync("You are now logged in.", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            return await step.PromptAsync(
                ConfirmPromptName,
                new PromptOptions
                {
                    Prompt = MessageFactory.Text($"Would you like to view your token? {tokenResponse.Token}"),
                    Choices = new List<Choice> { new Choice("Yes"), new Choice("No") },
                },
                cancellationToken);
        }

        await step.Context.SendActivityAsync("Login was not successful please try again.", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        return Dialog.EndOfTurn;
    }
```

Second Waterfall step.

```
    private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> DisplayTokenAsync(WaterfallStepContext step, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = (bool)step.Result;
        if (result)
        {
            var prompt = await step.BeginDialogAsync(LoginPromptName, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            var tokenResponse = (TokenResponse)prompt.Result;
            if (tokenResponse != null)
            {
                await step.Context.SendActivityAsync($"Here is your token {tokenResponse.Token}", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        return Dialog.EndOfTurn;
    }
```

What am I missing here? Thank you in advance. I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) guide and [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication) project.

**Edit:** I have the dialog set within the bot's constructor, added the prompts and the waterfall dialog to the set.

```
    var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
    {
        PromptStepAsync,
        LoginStepAsync,
        DisplayTokenAsync,
    };

    _dialogs.Add(new WaterfallDialog("authDialog", waterfallSteps));
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Nishan Chathuranga!!

I ran into this problem when I was creating a confirmation bot! One small change will have you on the right track. The Choice Prompt returns a string, not a boolean, so you're confusing it. But if you change it to a Confirm Prompt, you'll eliminate this issue.

In my dialog set, I added multiple prompt types:

```
// Add the prompts.
            Add(new ChoicePrompt(Inputs.Choice));
            Add(new NumberPrompt<int>(Inputs.Number));
            Add(new ConfirmPrompt(Inputs.Confirm));
```

And my list of Inputs:

```
private static class Inputs //aka types of prompts
    {
        public const string Choice = "choicePrompt";
        public const string Number = "numberPrompt";
        public const string Confirm = "confirmPrompt";
    }
```

Now, when I called on these prompts, if I called Inputs.Choice for something that needed a yes(true) or no(false) answer, it broke:

```
public static async Task<DialogTurnResult> ConfirmPhoneAsync(
            WaterfallStepContext stepContext,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var phoneNumber = stepContext.Context.Activity.Text;
            stepContext.Values[Outputs.PhoneNumber] = phoneNumber;

            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
                Inputs.Choice,
                new PromptOptions
                {
                    Prompt = MessageFactory.Text($"Is {phoneNumber} your phone number?"),
                    Choices = new List<Choice> { new Choice("yep"), new Choice("nah.") },
                },
                cancellationToken);
        }
```

[image: wrongChoice]

BUT!! If I changed that line to Input.Confirm (a prompt type limited to 'yes' or 'no', not a list of options), it worked as expected:

```
return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
                Inputs.Confirm,
                new PromptOptions
```

[image: rightChoice]

Let me know if you need any other assistance!

Comment: The `ConfirmPromptName` here is a `ConfirmPrompt()`, It is defined as this. `
_dialogs.Add(new ConfirmPrompt(ConfirmPromptName));`

Comment: In that case, I believe your Confirm Prompt is mis-constructed. A ConfirmPrompt doesn't accept choices, just the dialog ID, a validator, and a locale (for language selection). Try commenting out the 'Choices' portion and rerunning it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you found a solution to this already, but I had run into the same problem and found a solution. 
The problems lies in not saving the DialogState in the ConversationState using the accessor's *save changes* method at the end of your OnTurnAsync Method. This is necessary and for the next time around your dialgogContext will contain an "ActiveDialog" which is your "authDialog".

// Save the updated dialog state into the conversation state.
await _accessors.ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);

You may also need to modify your BotAccessors Class to get have a reference to the ConversationState.

see link below for reference.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-prompts?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp